# Save button is disabled on edit form, cannot click it via UIAutomation

Tags: c#-4.0, ui-automation

This issue is in the same application as my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793040/if-i-programmatically-activate-a-window-in-another-application-can-i-detect-whe).

I'm experiencing some "odd" behavior, and I don't know if it's functioning as designed or if there's something wrong.  In the 3rd party application that I'm "injecting" data into I experience different behavior when I manually edit a record vs. when my automated application edits a record.

If I run the 3rd party application and manually edit a record, the 'Save' and 'Undo' buttons in the toolbar become enabled once I begin typing in a field.

If I run the 3rd party application, then run my automated application to edit a record, my application sets focus to the first field on the form, then "injects" the data into the fields (it actually looks like someone is typing it in very fast) but the 'Save' and 'Undo' buttons stay disabled the whole time.  I try to invoke the 'Save' button when I reach the bottom of the form, but I receive an error:

"*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotEnabledException' occurred in UIAutomationClient.dll
Additional information: The operation is not allowed on a nonenabled element.*"

I used [this code example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750582%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN to insert text in the textboxes of the 3rd party application.

```
if (!element.TryGetCurrentPattern(
      ValuePattern.Pattern, out valuePattern))
  {
    // Set focus for input functionality and begin.
    element.SetFocus();

    // Pause before sending keyboard input.
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    // Delete existing content in the control and insert new content.
    SendKeys.SendWait("^{HOME}");   // Move to start of control
    SendKeys.SendWait("^+{END}");   // Select everything
    SendKeys.SendWait("{DEL}");     // Delete selection
    SendKeys.SendWait(value);
  }
  // Control supports the ValuePattern pattern so we can  
  // use the SetValue method to insert content. 
  else
  {
    // Set focus for input functionality and begin.
    element.SetFocus();

    ((ValuePattern)valuePattern).SetValue(value);
  }
```

Perhaps I'm not searching the correct keywords, but Google has not been much help to me, and I only found one [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311800/how-to-enable-a-button-using-uiautomation-or-white) that seemed related.  If anyone can shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it.

TIA

---

**UPDATES:**

Re: why don't I check if button is enabled...

I don't know how to accomplish that, I was trying to do that earlier today.  I have an AutomationElement that references the 'Save' button, but the AutomationElement doesn't have an `Enabled` property.

```
AutomationElement toolbar = _mainWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "59392"));
AutomationElement saveButton = toolbar.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Commit Changes (CTRL S)"));
```

I tried to cast the AutomationElement as Button to check the Enabled property but I receive a build error "*Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'*"

```
if (!((Button)saveButton).Enabled)
    ((Button)saveButton).Enabled = true;
```

...ok, more searching lead to this: [UIAutomation Button Style Enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684112/ui-automation-button-style-enabled)
so now I can check if it is enabled, but I haven't figured out how to enable it yet.

2014.10.02 - I think it's not possible to enable a disabled button via UIAutomation.  So I will modify my question a bit.  If I manually click on an input field and begin typing the 'Save' button becomes enabled.  If I use UIAutomation to modify the record the 'Save' button does not become enabled.  So, how can I use UIAutomation to get the window into the same state that it's in when I manually edit the record?

Comment: Why not check to see if it is enabled and if not enabl eit since you already have a reference to the element in question.

Comment: @Sorceri I updated my question with the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the win32 api to send messages to the button directly. You can get all the handles you need from uiautomation just use the post message function like this.

```
    public TestSetup AutomationLibrary;

    [DllImport("User32.dll")] //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx
    public static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public int WM_ENABLE = 0x0A;
    public int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AutomationLibrary = new TestSetup();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement aeDesktop = AutomationLibrary.GetDesktop();
        AutomationElement aeForm1 = AutomationLibrary.GetAutomationElement("Form1", aeDesktop);
        AutomationElement aeDisabledButton = AutomationLibrary.GetAutomationElement("DISABLED", aeForm1);

        IntPtr windowIntPtr = new IntPtr(aeForm1.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
        IntPtr controlIntPtr = new IntPtr(aeDisabledButton.Current.NativeWindowHandle);

        PostMessage(windowIntPtr, WM_COMMAND, (IntPtr)WM_ENABLE, controlIntPtr);
    }
```

The TestSetup is my own home brewed automationlibrary but basically I am just getting automation elements then using the PostMessage function from User32.dll to enable the button. although it doesnt seem to actually enable the button, it does have the unintend consequence of clicking the button.

I used this article as reference for the postmessage function http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487938/Re-Active-Disabled-Controls

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Unfortunately I don't have time to try your suggestion, I ended up using less UI Automation than I wanted, and more SendKeys.Send() than I wanted.  For some reason I don't have issues with the button if I write all the fields using SendKeys.  I wasn't getting any replies and I have a deadline to meet, so I needed to just do whatever worked.